# Countable union of non Zariski-dense homomorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $F_k$ be a free group in $k>1$ letters, and $G$ a semi-simple algebraic group defined over reals $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the representation variety Hom$(F_k,G(\mathbb{R}))$. The points of this variety are the homomorphisms $\phi: F_k \to G(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the set of homomorphisms with non Zariski-dense image, i.e. those homomorphisms $\overline{\phi(F_k)}$ is a proper subgroup of $G(\mathbb{R})$, where the closure is considered in Zariski topology. Denote the subset of such homomorphisms by $\mathcal{F}$.
My question is whether $\mathcal{F}$ is Zariksi-dense in Hom$(F_k,G(\mathbb{R}))$ ?

Comment: For $k=1$ and for $G=\textbf{SL}_{2,\mathbb{R}}$, it appears to me that your subset of $\text{Hom}(F_1,G)=G$ contains an open subset of the set of real points that is Zariski dense.  An element of $\textbf{SL}_{2,\mathbb{R}}$ that is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in a maximal torus, and this is a proper closed subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @JasonStarr for $k=1$ every homomrphism has non-Zariski dense image, so the answer is obviously "yes". In fact, the answer is "yes" in general, as the set of Zariski dense homomorphisms is Zariski open - no need to go to a countable union.

Comment: @UriBader.  Perhaps you and I are reading the question differently.  According to what I read, the OP wants there to exist a countable collection of  closed subvarieties of $G$, each of which is a proper subset of $G$, such that $\mathcal{F}$ equals the union of these proper subsets.  Yet, for $k=1$, the subset $\mathcal{F}$ appears to equal all of $G$.  So $\mathcal{F}$ cannot equal a countable union of closed subsets of $G$ that are proper subsets.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Perhaps I should write $G(\mathbb{R})$.  I agree with @Jason Starr.

Comment: Please note the change: $k > 1 $.

Comment: @JasonStarr, right. Regardless what the OP wants, the following two points are valid: 1) The collection $\mathcal{F}$ coinsides with the real points of a subvariety, and 2) A variety cannot be written as a countable union of proper subvarieties.

Comment: If somebody understands the question I'd be happy to have a translation in standard mathematical language (with no misuse of "represented", or family for "set", etc);

Comment: user49908 do you regard finite cardinals as countable? in any case, the answer to the question as asked is "yes".

Comment: I do not understand the need for the second paragraph: " now consider the Zariski closure of $\mathcal{F}$,...". This Zariski closure does not play a role in the question. You are asking if the set $\mathcal{F}$ is itself a countable union of proper subvarieties.Am I correct?

Comment: I sort of better understand the idea. But I'm confused: you say "consider the Zariski closure of..." and then your question does not refer to this Zariski closure.

Comment: @Venkataramana . Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The new question is whether the closure is a countable union of proper closed subvarieties. This sounds weird: a Zariski-closed subset is never a countable union of closed proper subvarieties of itself. So it just asks whether this Zariski closure is a proper subset, i.e., whether $\mathcal{F}$ is not Zariski-dense. And the answer is yes iff $k\ge 2$. But of course it's better to know that the subset $\mathcal{F}$ itself is Zariski-closed.

Comment: @Ycor Thanks for directing me to ask the right question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: actually $\mathcal{F}$ is Zariski-closed in $G^k$. (And since $\mathcal{F}\neq G^k$ as soon as $k\ge 1$ and $G\neq\{1\}$, we deduce in this case that $\mathcal{F}$ is not Zariski-dense.)

---

All this can be performed over an algebraic closure, so in the following I never suppose anything to be defined over the reals.

Let $(V,\pi)$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ (of dimension $d_V$). Let $U_V$ be the set of $(g_1,\dots,g_k)\in G^k$ acting irreducibly on $V$. Then it means that the subalgebra generated by $\pi(g_1),\dots,\pi(g_k)$ contains $d_V^2$ linearly independent elements. This is a Zariski open condition.

By Chevalley's theorem, every proper subgroup is a point stabilizer in some representation. We perform this with every maximal Zariski-closed subgroup: these are finitely up to conjugacy (indeed they are either parabolic, or reductive; in the second case this means the normalizer of a semisimple subgroup, and there are finitely many semisimple subgroups up to conjugacy.) We thus get representations $V_1,\dots,V_n$ corresponding to maximal subgroups $M_1,\dots,M_n$. A subgroup contained in a conjugate of $M_i$ is non-irreducible on $V_i$. Hence if $(g_1,\dots,g_k)$ is in $U=\bigcap U_{V_i}$, then it generates a Zariski-dense subgroup and conversely being outside $U_{V_i}$ implies failure of Zariski-density. Thus $\mathcal{F}$ is the complement of $U$, and thus is Zariski-closed.

For $k\ge 2$ and $G\neq 1$ there are indeed Zariski-dense 2-generated subgroups and in this case $\mathcal{F}\neq G^k$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is not Zariski-dense.

Comment: "reductive also if I remember correctly" is the problem I faced. In fact much can be said. Maximal proper closed subgroups are either parabolic or normalizer of semisimple subgroups or nomalizer of maximal torus.  Parablic is fine due to compactness ( I am being vague here .I hope you don't mind.)  As for the latter two types, I am stuck. Because, for instance, the union of conjugates of maximal torus is dense, for semisimple elements are dense in $G$.

Comment: @user49908 every reductive subgroup that is maximal is the normalizer of its derived subgroup, a semisimple subgroup. A semisimple group has finitely many conjugacy classes of semisimple subgroups (I don't have a definitive argument but I'm pretty sure).

Comment: Yes. Right. Thats a theorem due to Richardon.